# How to always show "read more..." link?

Tags: views, 8

Is there an easy way to always show the "read more..." link when text is trimmed in a view?

Was looking for an "Always show read-more link" option for cases when the text is not long enough to be trimmed, but there is none unfortunately. :(

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

[image: View field options - read-more link]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add the trim limit for the content field what you want.
2. Add the link to content field in the view and put the display content.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply Karuna.  Do you know what the machine name is for  "Link to Content"?  I ask because I am providing a customized template for the view by overriding **views-view-fields.html.twig** and need to figure out how to display the "Link to Content" field.  I tried `{{ link_to_content }}` and `{{ fields.field_link_to_content.content }}`, but neither worked.  Any ideas?  Thanks again!

Comment: Found out that this works: `{{ fields.view_node.content }}`, but running into a formatting issue now.  When content is stripped and the 'Read more' is added, the content's closing `</p>` tag comes **after** the 'Read more' link.  However, if content is **not** stripped, then the content's closing `</p>` tag comes **before** the 'Read more' link, which forces it to appear on a separate line. :(  Trying to figure out a solution...

Comment: Accomplished what I was trying to do with the following in **views-view-fields.html.twig**:

`<div class="description">{{ fields.field_event_description.content|striptags }} {{ fields.view_node.content }}</div>`  The 'striptags' filter strips the offending `<p>` tags (and all other HTML tags, unfortunately), but for this short listing view, it is not significant, as most descriptions do not contain (much) markup in the short, truncated part that is being displayed.  Could also use replace.

Thanks again for your help with the 'Link to Content' field suggestion in the View configuration!!!